# Cannot connect to local ip address OSX (Mavericks)

Tags: macos, networking, unix

Here is the situation:

- I can ping and connect to localhost / 127.0.0.1
- I can resolve `hostname` (dig / nslookup)
- I can ping my ip local ip address (10.63.66.185) and hostname from another machine
- I can connect to a running service on my local machine from another machine (nc -l 12345)
- I cannot ping / connect to my local ip address (10.63.66.185 -> 10.63.66.185)
- The OSX firewall is off and no other security products are being run
- The routing table looks fine (lo0 exists and 10.63.66.185 -> lo0)
- It persists even after a reboot

So I am stumped as to why I cannot connect to my own ip.  Does anyone have any idea or need more information?  Here is the routing table:

```
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            10.63.64.1         UGSc           22        0     en1
10.63.64/22        link#5             UCS             9        0     en1
10.63.64.1         0:0:c:7:ac:40      UHLWIir        23       24     en1   1184
10.63.64.140       a0:88:b4:99:18:14  UHLWI           0        0     en1   1066
10.63.65.113       8c:70:5a:ba:f4:c4  UHLWIi          2       95     en1   1192
10.63.65.115       link#5             UHLWI           0        4     en1
10.63.65.119       127.0.0.1          UHS             0        0     lo0
10.63.65.129       0:26:c6:81:6f:82   UHLWIi          3     1848     en1   1162
10.63.66.30        a4:4e:31:26:8b:58  UHLWI           0        0     en1   1143
10.63.67.31        58:94:6b:22:4b:20  UHLWI           0        0     en1   1132
10.63.67.95        6c:88:14:8:45:10   UHLWI           0        0     en1   1118
10.63.67.140       8:11:96:8a:d9:f4   UHLWI           0        0     en1   1150
17.149.32.32       10.63.64.1         UGHWIi          1       25     en1
23.3.105.161       10.63.64.1         UGHWIi          1        6     en1
23.21.158.158      10.63.64.1         UGHWIi          1        7     en1
23.74.51.182       10.63.64.1         UGHWIi          1       35     en1
64.94.107.44       10.63.64.1         UGHWIi          1        4     en1
64.94.107.60       10.63.64.1         UGHWIi          1        4     en1
64.156.167.77      10.63.64.1         UGHWIi          1       10     en1
72.21.91.19        10.63.64.1         UGHWIi          2       12     en1
72.21.91.121       10.63.64.1         UGHWIi          1       10     en1
74.125.28.95       10.63.64.1         UGHWIi          1        4     en1
74.125.28.104      10.63.64.1         UGHWIi          1       15     en1
127                127.0.0.1          UCS             0        0     lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH            164   243514     lo0
169.254            link#5             UCS             0        0     en1
172.18.51.138      10.63.64.1         UGHWIi          4     3928     en1
172.18.64.47       10.63.64.1         UGHWIi          1       15     en1
173.194.33.134     10.63.64.1         UGHWIi          1        6     en1
173.194.33.140     10.63.64.1         UGHWIi          1       13     en1
173.194.33.142     10.63.64.1         UGHWIi          1      138     en1
173.194.33.150     10.63.64.1         UGHWIi          1       18     en1
184.73.187.202     10.63.64.1         UGHWIi          1       15     en1
190.93.244.58      10.63.64.1         UGHWIi          2       20     en1
198.252.206.16     10.63.64.1         UGHWIi          1       13     en1
198.252.206.25     10.63.64.1         UGHW3I          0       48     en1     13
205.251.242.54     10.63.64.1         UGHW3I          0       17     en1     16
```

And `ifconfig -a`:

```
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=10b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_HWTAGGING,AV>
    ether a8:20:66:44:1d:e5 
    media: autoselect (none)
    status: inactive
en1: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 5c:96:9d:84:72:75 
    inet 10.63.65.119 netmask 0xfffffc00 broadcast 10.63.67.255
    media: autoselect
    status: active
en3: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=60<TSO4,TSO6>
    ether d2:00:10:ec:2a:40 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
fw0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 4078
    lladdr 10:dd:b1:ff:fe:0e:c2:a4 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
bridge0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=63<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6>
    ether aa:20:66:44:34:00 
    Configuration:
    id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
    maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
    root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
    ipfilter disabled flags 0x2
    member: en3 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
        ifmaxaddr 0 port 6 priority 0 path cost 0
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    media: <unknown type>
    status: inactive
p2p0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 2304
    ether 0e:96:9d:84:72:75 
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive
```

Comment: Does this problem survive a reboot? Also, can you provide `ifconfig -a` and `netstat -rnaf inet` output?

Comment: Yes, it persists even after a reboot.  I attached the command outputs.

Comment: *Just in case, I have to ask:* Were you using the right IP address for your machine? And did you include the command output from the right machine? In your original writeup, you said 10.63.66.185, but in this command output, it was 10.63.65.119. I figure it's most likely that the machine is on DHCP and happened to be assigned a different IP address, but I thought I should ask.

Comment: I am on DHCP so it will possible change: